# Is it still possible to host a CSGO lan party without internet access?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, hosting

I am wanting to host a lan party with friends for CSGO, but the location will have patchy internet access.  Following the introduction of GSLTs and the removal of listen servers, is it still possible to host a game without internet access?

i.e. **is there a way of starting a csgo dedicated server for a LAN game only, without needing to connect to the internet?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Start steam in Offline-Mode (should be done automatically if you don't have Internet anyway).
2. Make sure all of your computers are connected via LAN.
3. In console type: map *map*.
4. Kick the bots with the **console** command: `bot_kick all`.
5. Allow people to join via LAN on your server with the command: `sv_lan 1` (not sure if it is on `1` or `0` by default).
6. With the command `status` you can see details of your server (e.g. IP).
7. Your friends are able to join your server with the command `connect <IP>`.

Matter, that neither Achievements nor the EXP System are available off-line.
Connecting should be also possible via the client (Community Server), but I don't have personal experience with that and heard that it is buggy.

Don't forget to allow CS:GO through the Firewall when the notification pops up.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I'm if I try to run an offline with bots game whilst steam is offline I even get kicked from my own game, and I can't seem to get any other machines to connect.  I think it's related to the update/issue mentioned here: [link](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=3299916)

Answer (score 0):

You are either not gonna be able to open CS:GO or you are only gonna be able to play against bots. It's an online game so there is no comps, no casual no deathmatch, no nothing.

Comment: Are you sure? The other answer somewhat contradicts your own, especially if there is a console command to spesificly enable a LAN-mode.